# Move page to element defined by hash with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with numerous Picasa albums embedded into it. Each embedded album is inside a `<div>` with a unique ID.

I want to be able to point my browser to /photos/#UNIQUEID and for the page to load focussed on the correct album.

How can I do this using JavaScript? My page is: http://goo.gl/jDZIK

Comment: where are you getting stuck?

Comment: `window.location.hash` should give you the "UNIQUEID" part of the URL, if you want to attempt a JavaScript approach. If you just want the page to advance to the correct album, put an `<a name="UNIQUEID"></a>` in or around the `<h1>` title elements above each album, and the browser will do the rest for you.

Comment: take the / out.  just point to /photos#UNIQUEID

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Or, if its easier, what exactly is happening that you don't like

Answer (score 3):

Why would you do this using JavaScript?
It's already a default behavior of the browsers.

http://www.outtheremusic.net/photos/#summer2010

This link scrolls me down to the correct image with those browsers I had in hand to test:
Firefox,
Opera,
Chrome,
Internet Explorer

So the answer to your question is: You don't need to do it, browser already does it.
If you want to scroll down to a picture while clicking something on the page and without reloading it, that's a different story (and a different question in that matter)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = '#HASH_NAME'?
```

Edited. Thanks to Cory for pointing out my obvious mistake & sorry about that! ;) Cheers!

Comment: -1: This *sets* the hash, and doesn't answer the question. How will that give focus to the correct section of the page?

Comment: Ah yes sorry about that, you're correct! OK, then why not set it with window.location.href = '#HASH_NAME'? It works in Chrome/Opera/IE7+/FireFox I just tried it ;)

Comment: I removed my downvote because of a technically viable approach, although I'm not advocating the use of JavaScript as an actual solution.

Comment: @Cory, I agree regarding not using JavaScript to do such things whenever possible, however it is still a correct answer to the OP question, asking "How can I do this using JavaScript?". Also, there might be times when using JavaScript would be the only way do achieve some sort of automated scrolling to named anchors, for example. Can't see that of much use, still, it answers the question. ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your page you have several `<h1>` title elements, one above each album. If, for example, you wanted the URL `~/photos/#album1` to jump to the area with the heading "Album 1", you just have to modify your HTML a little. The "old fashioned" way of doing this was to provide an anchor `<a>` element with a matching `name` attribute. So,

```
<h1>Album 1</h1>
```

Would change to:

```
<a name="album1"></a><h1>Album 1</h1>
```

Or, modern browsers will jump to any element with an `id` that matches the hash value, so you could simply do:

```
<h1 id="album1">Album 1</h1>
```

The browser should take care of the rest. Just make sure all your `id`s on your page are unique. FYI: I didn't like the idea of jumping to the `<div>` elements, because then the heading gets cut out of the viewport.

Answer (score -1):

using jQuery you can specify then when someone clicks on the div you send them to the  location you want.

```
$("div").click(function(){
  var UniqueID = $(this).prop('id');

  window.location.href = "www.servername.com/photos/#" + UniqueID;

});
```